# What should I consider before developing in .NET on Windows 7?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-7

Does anyone use the Windows 7 preview release for .NET development?

Do things like SQL Server Express 2005/2008, VS.NET 2005/2008 work on it fine?
How about IIS?

Any other things I should be taking into consideration?

Answer (score 5):

I've been using Windows 7 as my primary operating system since its beta. It works pretty well with Visual Studio 2008 SP1, IIS 7.5, SQL Server 2008 SP1. I haven't had any problems so far.

Comment: Same here! If anything, I'm getting better performance out of VS since Windows7 is a little less demanding of my slightly aged laptop.

Comment: @Dillie-O slightly better than Vista? Or XP?

Answer (score 0):

i've been using it since the beta build (7000), and now RC build (7100). no issues, maybe some glitches but i can't remember any particular so nothing that makes real problems. oh, forgot to mention - i use both 32-bit and 64-bit on my rather old notebook and recently built desktop machine. both work fine.

VS2008 works ok, 2005 i think has to be run as administrator for the debugger to work, or some glitch it was, but not 100% positive any more what was it..

SQL2005/2008 Express work fine.

haven't tried IIS, the VS built-in web server works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I too have been using Windows 7 (Beta, RC1) with Visual Studio 2008, MySql, IIS 7.5 (and a ton of addons), Eclipse 3.4, and VMWare for running Linux - everything runs very smooth.

It is a dream come true.  Really.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using Win 7 64bit for development heavily since beta.

VS 2008 + SP1, SQL Server Express 2008, TSVN 64Bit with a bit of development tools for Office 2007 Add-ins, Azure and Silverlight

There were a few issues under beta, but they were gone after upgrading to Windows 7 RC. Works like a snap.